# 1x1 round plate with studs on both sides

Tags: part-identification

I apologize for the poor picture quality, but can anyone identify this piece I found in my collection. It's a 1x1 round plate with studs on both sides. [image]It looks similar to [Wheel Center Small with Stub Axles (Pulley Wheel)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3464#T=C)
 but it's smaller.
[image: 1x1 round plate with studs on both sides]

Comment: Do the studs say Lego?

Comment: The studs are the open/hollow kind, so there's no trademark.

Comment: My best guess is what @Joost already answered.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the double stud part of a [4081b Plate, Modified 1 x 1 with Light Attachment - Thick Ring](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4081b) where the 1x1 plate part broke off.

[image: 4081b]

It comes in a couple of metallic colors

Does your part has a break mark?

Comment: yes, there appears to be a bit of a nub where something was broken off.  So, I guess Ican't just buy these on bricklink, right?

Comment: Well, you can. But: some disassembly required.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the make, but I have one of these and there is no sign of a break mark so seems to have been made like this.

Could possibly be one of these [Cobi 1X1 1/3 Duo](https://cobi.pl/en/blocks-by-piece/general-spare-parts/1x1-13-duo,art,12866.html) parts:

[image: Cobi 1X1 1/3 Duo part render]